# PHPUnit: Fatal error Class ClassName not found

Tags: php, phpunit, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to build a Unit Testing environment for a CodeIgniter application. I'm following [this book](https://github.com/efendibooks/codeigniter-handbook-vol-3/) and got PHPUnit to work.

I'm at a point where I'm testing some code in a model:

```
    public function testPresent()
{
    $tracker = new Tracker_model();

    $tableObj = (object)array( 'type' => $this->expectedConstants['TABLE']);
    $visitsObj = (object)array( 'type' => $this->expectedConstants['VISITS']);

    $tableObj = $tracker->present($tableObj);
    $visitsObj = $tracker->present($visitsObj);

    $this->assertThat($tableObj, $this->isInstanceOf('Tracker_TablePresenter'));
    $this->assertThat($visitsObj, $this->isInstanceOf('Tracker_VisitsPresenter'));
}
```

The code being tested is this:

```
    public function present($obj)
{
    if( isset($obj->type) )
    {
        switch($obj->type)
        {
            case self::VISITS: $type = 'Visits'; break;
            case self::TABLE: 
            default: $type = 'Table'; break;
        }

        $className = 'Tracker_'.$type.'Presenter';
        $obj = new $className($obj, 'tracker');
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

It should load the class `Tracker_TablePresenter` which is in the file `presenters/tracker/TablePresenter.php`. I can't explain all the logic behind this mechanism because it would be too long and complex, but I know it works, because on another computer with the exact same code it's passing the test. On my computer, instead, I get this error:

```
.......PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tracker_TablePresenter' not found in /home/.../application/models/tracker_model.php on line 42
```

More information on the error:

```
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:776
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:831
PHP  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
PHP  13. Tracker_modelTest->testPresent() /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
PHP  14. Tracker_model->present() /.../application/tests/models/Tracker_modelTest.php:38
```

I'm working on Ubuntu, while the other guy who has the code working is using a Mac. This is the output of my php -v

```
PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 16:09:26) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.3.0dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

I also tried downgrading php to 5.3, since he is using the 5.3, but nothing. Same error.
Can you help me understanding what's going on?

Edit:

This is the content of the file `TablePresenter.php`

```
<?php

class Tracker_TablePresenter extends Presenter
{
public function values()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    if (!isset($this->values)) {
        $this->ci->load->model('value_model', 'value');
        $this->values = $this->ci->value->getManyForTracker($this->tracker->id);
    }
    return $this->values;
}
}

?>
```

Edit 2:

I changed the code in the `present` function as suggested by JoDev like this:

```
    public function present($obj)
{
if( isset($obj->type) )
{
    switch($obj->type)
    {
        case self::VISITS: $type = 'Visits'; break;
        case self::TABLE: 
        default: $type = 'Table'; break;
    }

    //use include, but require is to force an internal error if the file isn't founded!
    require_once('presenters/tracker/'.$type.'Presenter.php');

    $className = 'Tracker_'.$type.'Presenter';
    $obj = new $className($obj, 'tracker');
}
return $obj;
}
```

Now I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from .../phpunit.xml

.......PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tracker_TablePresenter' not found in .../application/models/tracker_model.php on line 61
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:776
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:831
PHP  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
PHP  13. Tracker_modelTest->testPresent() .../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
PHP  14. Tracker_model->present() .../application/tests/models/Tracker_modelTest.php:37
```

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  include(presenters/tracker/TablePresenter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: models/tracker_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 58</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  include(): Failed opening 'presenters/tracker/TablePresenter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.../vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:.../vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.../vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:.../vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:.../vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit:.../vendor/symfony/yaml:.../vendor/pdepend/pdepend/src/main/php:.../vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/main/php:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')</p>
<p>Filename: models/tracker_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 58</p>

</div>%
```

Comment: You're saying that it should be loading the class `Tracker_TablePresenter`, but the error message is saying it can't find the class `Tracker_VisitsPresenter`. Probably a stupid question, but have you made sure that the file is present and correctly named for that class? (presumably located at `presenters/tracker/VisitsPresenter.php`)

Comment: I edited it. It's just that while I was writing the question I commented a line in the code and tried with the other class, `Tracker_VisitsPresenter`, but the problem was the same. So I just pasted the wrong error message.

Comment: So, neither class is being autoloaded?

Comment: exactly. The code for both classes is almost the same, so mine was just a desperate try

Comment: Okay, then, if the files exist, and the value of `$className` is correct when you try to instantiate the class, then there is most likely an issue with the autoloading script.. so without being able to see how that's working, I don't know how to solve this

Comment: And what is the system on which the test passes? Isn't it a Windows, by chance?

Comment: @rixo, I wrote it in the question that the other guy is using a Mac

Comment: @Carlo Ok, sorry, I interpreted "because on another computer with the exact same code it's passing the test" as yet another computer.

Comment: is it related to naming 'tracker' as 'Tracker' to the folder which appears in the path presenters/tracker/

Comment: what do you mean exactly, @jospratik?

Comment: Can you POST the beginning of the `Tracker_VisitsPresenter` and `Tracker_TablePresenter` class?

Comment: @JoDev I edited the question and added the code of Tracker_TablePresenter. The other class is just empty, for now.

Comment: How is autoloading of the classes handled?

Answer (score 2):

Please, can you try to include the class manualy by using :

```
public function present($obj)
{
    if( isset($obj->type) )
    {
        switch($obj->type)
        {
            case self::VISITS: $type = 'Visits'; break;
            case self::TABLE: 
            default: $type = 'Table'; break;
        }

        //use include, but require is to force an internal error if the file isn't founded!
        require_once('Presenters/Tracker/'.$type.'Presenter.php');

        $className = 'Tracker_'.$type.'Presenter';
        $obj = new $className($obj, 'tracker');
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Thank's to this test, you will be able to know if the error is in the `autoloader` or anywhere else!
And tell me what appends...

**[EDIT @13/06/2013 10:00]**

Where is the file calling TablePresenter in the tree?

To fix the problem, you have (in my opinion) three possibilities :
-1) Add parent directory of Presenter in the `include_path` of the serveur! 
    (to retrieve actual includings, use `get_include_path()`)
-2) Be sure to use good URL to include the file
-3) Use absolute URL

Answer (score 0):

I bet it has to do with file permissions on your machine. The script can't find the file because Apache can't open it.

Comment: no, it's not this. I tried putting it 777, but the error is still there

Comment: @hakre: it's possible that I'm really bad at trouble-shooting, but in that case chmodding that file to 777 (I didn't chmodded everything as you are saying) was the quickest thing I could do.

Comment: quick? you asked on Jun 1. This was answered yesterday. For trouble-shooting (especially quick one) it's important to not guess around  - actually it's okay to guess around in the first five minutes of it but if it didn't lead to results within these 5 minutes, stop with guessing around. That's just what I'm trying to say here. Instead develop check-points and then test in your trouble shooting if expectations are matched or not.

Comment: I don't get your point. I tried the 777 thing after Copenhagen suggested that it might be a permission problem. He answered yesterday and I tried it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case-sensitiveness issue (@jospratik 's question). As far as i know OSX is not case sensitive. So this is an issue you would have when working on linux vs mac/win.

Change the folder names to start with uppercase char like

```
Presenters/Tracker/VisitsPresenter.php
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I've already tried changin cases in classes and in filenames. I tried again now just to be sure, but too bad that's not the problem.

Comment: I was not talking about class names and filenames.. but directory names. Did you take a look at that?

Answer (score 0):

seems to me like a problem with Class 'Tracker_TablePresenter' which couldnt be found. did you use the correct namespace?